# Load data already registered in a form - VueJS - Bootstrap-Vue

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have a form that has select linked, that is, when one select is filled in the other select is also filled in with the respective code of the other select. The problem is that when opening the modal with the value of that field, it is not loading the value, I don't know if the reason is the v-model which is different.

**Template**

```
<template>
    <div class="Datas">
        <b-row class="mt-0 mb-0">
            <b-col align="left" md="3" sm="12">
                <b-button variant="primary" @click="viewModal()" class="mr-2" size="sm">
                    <span> New</span>
                </b-button>
            </b-col>
        </b-row>

        <b-table hover striped small outlined :items="valuesLoaded" :sort-by.sync="sortBy" :fields="fields" responsive="sm" class="mt-0 mb-0" id="table-A">
            <template slot="actions" slot-scope="data">
                <b-button @click="viewModal(data.item)" variant="primary" class="mr-2" size="sm">
                    <span> Edit</span>
                </b-button>
            </template>
        </b-table>

        <div>
            <b-modal ref="viewModal"
                title="Add/Edit Form"
                size="lg"               
                @hidden="reset"
                @ok="save"
                ok-variant="primary"
                cancel-title="Cancel">

                <div>
                    <input id="dataUnique-id" type="hidden" v-model="dataUnique.id"/>
                    <b-row class="mt-0 mb-0">
                        <b-col md="6" sm="12">
                            <b-form-group label="Value 1:" label-for="dataUnique-value1" label-size="sm" class="mt-0 mb-0">
                                <b-form-select 
                                    v-model="dataSelect"
                                    size="sm">
                                    <option :key="obj.value2" v-for="obj in informations" v-bind:value="obj">{{ obj.value1 }}</option>
                                </b-form-select>
                            </b-form-group>
                        </b-col>
                        <b-col md="6" sm="12">
                            <b-form-group label="Value 2:" label-for="dataUnique-value2" label-size="sm" class="mt-0 mb-0">
                                <b-form-select 
                                    v-model="dataSelect"
                                    size="sm">
                                    <option :key="obj.value2" v-for="obj in informations" v-bind:value="obj">{{ obj.value2 }}</option>
                                </b-form-select>
                            </b-form-group>
                        </b-col>
                        <b-col md="6" sm="12">
                            <b-form-group label="Base:" label-for="dataUnique-base" label-size="sm" class="mt-0 mb-0">
                                <b-form-select v-model="dataUnique.base" 
                                    :options="optionBase"
                                    size="sm" />
                            </b-form-group>
                        </b-col>
                        <b-col md="6" sm="12">
                            <b-form-group label="Rulez:" label-for="dataUnique-rulez" label-size="sm" class="mt-0 mb-0">
                                <b-form-select v-model="dataUnique.rulez" 
                                    :options="optionRulez"
                                    size="sm" />
                            </b-form-group>
                        </b-col>
                    </b-row>
                </div>
            </b-modal>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    name: 'Test',
    components: { },
    data: function() {
        return {
            dataUnique: {},
            dataBackend: [],
            optionBase: [
                { value: 'base1', text: 'Base 1' },
                { value: 'base2', text: 'Base 2' },
                { value: 'base3', text: 'Base 3' },
                { value: 'base4', text: 'Base 4' },
                { value: 'base5', text: 'Base 5' },
            ],            
            optionRulez: [
                { value: 'rulez1', text: 'Rulez 1' },
                { value: 'rulez2', text: 'Rulez 2' },
                { value: 'rulez3', text: 'Rulez 3' },
            ],
            informations: [],
            fields: [
                { key: 'value1', label: 'Value 1', sortable: true },
                { key: 'value2', label: 'Value 2', sortable: true },
                { key: 'actions', label: 'Actions' } 
            ],
            dataSelect: {
                value1: '',
                value2: ''
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        viewModal (dataUnique) {
            if(dataUnique != null) {
                const edition = {
                    dataSelect: {
                        value2: dataUnique.value2
                    },
                    ...dataUnique
                }
                this.loadUniqueData(edition)
            } else {
                this.dataUnique = {}
            }
            this.$refs.viewModal.show()
        },
        loadData() {
            const url = `${baseApiUrl}/dataBackend`
            axios.get(url).then(res => {
                this.dataBackend = res.data.data
            })
            .catch(showError)
        },
        loadInformations() {
            const url = `${baseApiUrl}/informations`
            axios.get(url).then(res => {
                this.informations = res.data
            })
        },
        loadUniqueData(dataUnique) {
            this.dataUnique = { ...dataUnique }
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.loadData()
        this.loadInformations()
    }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

When I click on the "Edit" button that are in the "Action" table, it should be loaded in the "modal" that is opened, the values ​​contained within each "v-model", but this does not happen in "dataSelect" that is the first and second select in the code.

However, if I try to add a new form, everything works correctly, even when I make the first selection, the second select is automatically filled.

**I think the problem occurs because the first two select, are made with the v-model different from the other two below, since the two below when I try to open the form, they are filled with the values ​​of the dataUnique object. That is the correct expected result.**

```
<b-form-select 
    v-model="dataSelect"
    size="sm">
    <option :key="obj.value2" v-for="obj in informations" v-bind:value="obj">{{ obj.value1 }}</option>
</b-form-select>
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what the selects are meant to be doing. You have both selects accepting the dataSelect and giving the `obj.value2` value on the options but are displaying different text (`obj.value1` in one and `obj.value2` in the other). Won't one select have an option value of `obj.value1` and the other `obj.value2` and not both being `obj.value2`? If that's the case you could set the v-model values to `dataSelect.value1` and `dataSelect.value2`

Comment: @Hides He had done exactly that before, but it still didn't work, and he still lost the selection option with automatic filling in both select.

Comment: Where in your methods do you update the dataSelect? I can see you are updating it in the dataUnique object but never the dataSelect object outside of that which you are using for the selects. Would it then be `v-model="dataUnique.dataSelect"`?

Comment: @Hides The last method does this: loadUniqueData(dataUnique)

Comment: But that doesn't update the dataSelect, only the dataUnique.DataSelect. So this might work `loadUniqueData(dataUnique) {
            this.dataUnique = { ...dataUnique } this.dataSelect = { ...dataUnique.dataSelect }
        }`

Comment: @Hides Incredible answer, solved my problem! Thank you!!!

Comment: No problem, I've added the answer below for better readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dataselect is not being updated. You can update it in your loadUniqueData function

```
loadUniqueData(dataUnique) { 
    this.dataUnique = { ...dataUnique } 
    this.dataSelect = { ...dataUnique.dataSelect } 
}
```